# main can't find method from another file

Tags: c

How can I use a method from another file in main.c?

I created a method in my list.c file and try to print it out in my main.c file. When I try that it gives me the error "current undeclared,current2 undeclared,head undeclared".

- added list.h

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"
    
typedef struct list_struct *List;
    
    
int main(){
    
            
createList();
printf("%d %d %d" , head->value, current->value, current2->value);
return 0;
        
        
}
```

list.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"
            
typedef struct list_struct *List;
            
struct node {
int value;
struct node *next;
};
            
List createList(){
            
struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                head->value = 45;
                head->next = NULL;
            
struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                current->value = 98;
                current->next = NULL;
                current->next = current;
            
struct node *current2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                current2->value = 3;
                current2->next = NULL;
                return 0;
            
}
```

list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

#ifndef BOOLEAN
    #define BOOLEAN
    typedef enum {false, true} Bool;
#endif
/**
 * Forward pointer declaration to an internal implementation specific hidden list structure.
 */
typedef struct list_struct *List;
/**
 * List life-cycle functions create and delete list or remove a single node with index
 */
List createList();
void deleteList(List head);
List removeAt(List head, int index);

#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

Comment: You didn't post `list.h`

Comment: Is that `list.c` or `list.h`?

Comment: Where is `head` defined? Inside the function? wont work

Comment: How is `main()` supposed to see something that's (as far as we can tell) local to the `createList` function? If you want these to be shared, you want to declare them as `extern`s in either `main.c` or something it includes, and _stop_ declaring them as function-local.

Comment: Both `main.c` and `list.c` include `list.h`.  But you didn't post that file at all.  That file is KEY to your problem.

Comment: Sorry but... seems you have misunderstood how global variables works.... But don't worry... global variables are bad so just forget them

Comment: @abelenky We should see `list.h` but no matter what it contains, it wont help

Comment: `current->next = current;` hmmm... a circular list with a single element

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how can i declare them as extern ?

Comment: Don't declare anything extern. createList *returns a value*. There is a reason for that.

Comment: Furthermore, struct list_struct is defined locally in list.c and not in list h. There is a reason for that too.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you do

```
printf("%d %d %d" , head->value, current->value, current2->value);
```

which means that `head`, `current` and `current2` must be available as global variables from another compilation unit.

But you don't do that... you define them as local variables inside `createList`.

You need to move them out of the function like:

```
struct node *head;

List createList(){
            
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->value = 45;
    head->next = NULL;
```

and then in `list.h` you need:

```
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};
extern struct node *head;
```

And the same for `current` and `current2`

**That said...**  Don't use globals...

Define the variables in `main` and pass them as arguments to the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) in main.c it gives now the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct node'"

Comment: @Frisik oh... I forgot something... See the updated answer